# SQL Match Against Fulltext Index is slow when searching common terms

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, fulltext-index

Simple PHP search page with three fields querying a MySQL database with millions of rows. The data consists of profiles, mostly USA.

Fulltext indexing increases speed by a factor of 9.6 when the search term is rare (eg "Canada").

Fulltext indexing slows speed by a factor of 3.6 when the search term is common (eg "United States").

Is there some way to enjoy the benefits of both technique? Maybe searching only a small portion of the table and constructing a "MATCH AGAINST" query if the term is rare (found in less than half of the records) and a standard "LIKE" query if the term is common? That sounds like a convoluted solution. I want a better way.

Here is my SQL and search times:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE `country` LIKE '%canada%'
```

1.14 seconds (slow)

```
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country)
AGAINST(' +canada' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND country LIKE '%canada%
```

0.12 seconds (fast)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE `country` LIKE '%united states%'
```

1.09 seconds (comparatively fast)

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country)
AGAINST(' +united +states' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND country LIKE '%united states%
```

3.9 seconds (slow)

Comment: Mysql's match is the worst fulltext search engine ever possible. Do yourself a favor, install ElasticSearch which is built for the exact purpose. It wouldn't even notice your millions at all, givin the search result in an instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to generate my own list of stopwords. I downloaded a sample of data and found the most common terms using Python. Common terms are excluded from MATCH queries through PHP. In my data, "United" and "States" are common terms:

```
$SQL =  "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country)
AGAINST('+sales +united +states' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND country LIKE '%united states% AND tagline LIKE '%sales%'"
```

Becomes:

```
$SQL =  "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country)
AGAINST('+sales' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND country LIKE '%united states% AND tagline LIKE '%sales%'"
```

When all of the search terms are "common" the MATCH statement is removed entirely:

```
$SQL =  "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH(tagline, location, country)
AGAINST('+united +states' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND country LIKE '%united states%"
```

Becomes:

```
$SQL =  "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `mytable` WHERE country LIKE '%united states%"
```

The best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

If you could know that the search is on a country name and that you need to look only in the `country` column, then this would be much faster than any of the above:

```
... WHERE country = 'canada'
```

What were the COUNTs from each query?  That would help explain the timings.  How many rows in the table?

Meanwhile, your FT queries are *not* the same as your LIKE queries.  So, I don't want to discuss why the speeds are different.

Comment: Yes, exact match would certainly make sense for the country field. I will implement that. The wildcards are because the other fields are like, "Staten Island New York" and "Paris Metropolitan Area". 
The FT and LIKE queries produce the same results with the same count. The FT queries are simply honing in on records that contain the search term in any field and subsequently performing a LIKE query on the results. This is what you recommended.